# Nested Multiple choice field serialize in Django and VueJS app

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-serializer

I have multiple choice nested serializer, I am able to get the value but  during  patch call **subjects** not getting updated

Here User and Subject are two models,

```
**Model.py**

class Subject(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', 
                                  serialize=False, 
                                  auto_created=True, 
                                  primary_key=True)
    ENG = "ENGLISH"
    HND = "HINDI"

    SUBJECT = (
        (ENG, "English"),
        (HND, "Hindi"),
    )

    subject = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=SUBJECT, default=ENG)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject


class User(AbstractUser):
    uid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', 
                                  serialize=False, 
                                  auto_created=True, 
                                  primary_key=True)
    TEACHER = "Teacher"
    STUDENT = "Student"

    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=STUDENT)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user_type == User.TEACHER and self._state.adding:
            self.approved = False
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def syllabus(self):
        ret = self.teacher.syllabus_set.all()
        if ret:
            return ret
        else:
            return ''
```

Here is my serializer call

```
**serializers.py**

class TeacherProfileDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    teacher_date = AvailabilityDetails(many=True, read_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name', read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name', read_only=True)
    cities = CitySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    subject = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user = UserDetailsSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
                  'bio', 'teacher_cost', 'subject', 'teacher_date', 'cities')

    def get_subject(self, obj):
        subject_list = []
        for i in obj.subject.all():
            subject_list.append(i.subject)
        return subject_list
```

Here is my views.py call

```
**views.py**

class TeacherListCreateAPIView(APIView):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        #def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            self.logger.info("Geeting TeacherListCreateAPIView information")
            teacherList = Teacher.objects.filter(user__username=kwargs["username"])
            self.logger.info(teacherList)
            serializers = TeacherProfileDetails(teacherList, many=True)
            self.logger.info(serializers.data)
            return Response(serializers.data)
        def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user__username=kwargs['username'])
            serializers = TeacherProfileDetails(data=request.data, instance=teacher)
            self.logger.info(serializers)
            if serializers.is_valid():
                serializers.save()
                return Response(serializers.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializers.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is urls.py

```
path('teacher/<str:username>/details',
         TeacherListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name="teacher-details"),
```

Issue :

I am able to get the teacher details, but patch call not updating subject,  looks like I am doing some mistake in  **TeacherProfileDetails** while serializing subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) is ***read-only***. So, all fields in provided serializer are read-only.

You can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) serializer instead, both for read and write:

```
subjects = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    many=True,
    slug_field='subject',
    queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
)
```

For write better to add logic in the view to make `subjects` contain unique elements or even allow adding one subject from `patch` to already present subjects.

---

Or you can use two separate serializers - one for read (current one), and one for write (with just fields allowed to be changed - it can be SlugRelatedField, or even just ListField with custom `update()` method logic, etc).

Comment: Getting below error, where should I write queryset

`
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/...../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 108, in __init__
    'Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, '
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.
`

Comment: Added queryset.

Comment: Now it works, I am able to read and write with same SlugRelatedField, then why you recommend to have separate read and write

Comment: For more readability / more explicit. Here almost all fields are read-only, hard to guess on first look that one field is for write.

Comment: Also, SlugRelatedField may not be very intuitive in more advanced scenario - more interdependent fields, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Final question can you please help below one also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818278/nested-dictionary-need-to-serialized-in-django

Comment: i was creating a drf serializer where admins can add and removes users from a group. been having issues figuring it out until i came accross this anser. it solved my problem thanks.